# Angular.js multiple file attachments upload with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, restangular

I'm trying with Angular upload multiple files from a form. And the problem is that, the rails app only receives one file in the `params` hash.

I have a form to create an `article` and that `article` has multiple `article_attachments`

In the angular `article.js` service file, I'm uploading the form like so:

```
function(Upload, $http, $q) { 
  var article = {
    create: function(newArticleForm) {
      sendPayload(newArticleForm, 'POST', '/articles.json');
    }
  }

  sendPayload = function(formData, method, url) {
    var file_attachment, options, ref, ref1;
    file = (ref = formData.file) != null ? ref : [];
    var names = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < formData.file.length; ++i) 
      names.push(formData.file[i].name);
    options = {
      url: url,
      method: method,
      file: formData.file,
      file_form_data_name: names,
      fields: {
        article: {
          brand: formData.brand,
          price: formData.price,
          user_id: formData.user_id
        }
      }
    };
    return Upload.upload(options);
  };
  return article;
}
```

And console.log, indeed gives that it is sending multiple files, like as follows:
[image]

But the problem is on the rails side, on my `articles_controller.rb` file, the `params` hash only contains one of the files

```
def create
  @article = current_user.articles.new(article_params)
  begin
    @article.save!
    if params[:article][:file]
      params[:article][:file].each { |image| @article.article_attachments.create(url: image)}
    end
    render json: @article.to_json 
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid => e
    render json: @article.errors ## You might want to specify a json format as well    
    return 
  end
end

private

def article_params
  params.require(:article).permit(
    :price, :brand, :model,:provider,
    :internal_memory, :color,
    :article_state, :battery_included, :user_id,
    :file
  )
end

def process_params
  params[:article] = JSON.parse(params[:article])
                             .with_indifferent_access

end
```

the request params, that should contains 2 upload files:

```
{
   "article" => {
      "brand" => "LG",
      "price" => 123,
    "user_id" => 2
},
      "file" => #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fe458d5b760 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/ps/tt94sbxd3dz31rxvw3v1r8nw0000gn/T/RackMultipart20150913-2113-hwty51.jpg>, @original_filename="140911111141-photo-realism-sam-silva-ocelot-horizontal-large-gallery.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"140911111141-photo-realism-sam-silva-ocelot-horizontal-large-gallery.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">,
"controller" => "articles",
    "action" => "create",
    "format" => "json"
}
```

So what's missing here?

Comment: whats the request params hash?

Comment: btw, has_one :file? or has_many files?

Comment: has_many files relation, I updated with an example of a request params

Comment: you are sending one file

Comment: rails expectess files[] -

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your `article_params` to below

```
def article_params
  params.require(:article).permit( :price, :brand, :model,:provider, :internal_memory, :color, :article_state, :battery_included, :user_id, :file => [])
end
```

Comment: it didn't work, it receives only one file as an upload

Comment: field: [] is correct for an array in strong parameters

Comment: but for me it doenst look like you send article[files][] . you just send files[]. right ?

Comment: yes, I'm using restangular and following this blogpost http://bradleymosesjohnson.com/2015/06/11/file-attachments-in-angular/